# Corona SDK move object without it being effected by gravity

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, game-physics

So I am trying to make a Flappy Birdesque game to learn how to make games using Corona SDK. I have a top column that I want to be able to move linearly. So I am using `topColumn.setLinearVelocity()`, but I also have gravity set in the game so the bird can flap properly :). But my issue is that when the game starts, the pipes fall to the ground due to gravity. Is there a way to move the topColumn and bottomColumn without them being affected by gravity? They are dynamic bodies right now, but I don't know how to move them using static.

Any help?

```js
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()
physics.setGravity( 0, 100 )
...
function addColumns()
 
 height = math.random(display.contentCenterY - 200, display.contentCenterY + 200)

 topColumn = display.newImageRect('topColumn.png',100,714)
 topColumn.anchorX = 0.5
 topColumn.anchorY = 1
 topColumn.x = display.contentWidth
 physics.addBody(topColumn, "dynamic", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0})
 topColumn.y = height - 160
 topColumn:setLinearVelocity( -20,0 )
 
 bottomColumn = display.newImageRect('bottomColumn.png',100,714)
 bottomColumn.anchorX = 0.5
 bottomColumn.anchorY = 0
 bottomColumn.x = display.contentWidth
 bottomColumn.y = height + 160
 physics.addBody(bottomColumn, "dynamic", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0})
 bottomColumn:setLinearVelocity( -20,0 )

end 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need kinematic bodies.

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/bodyType.html)

> "dynamic" — dynamic bodies are fully simulated. They can be moved
>   manually in code, but normally they move according to forces like
>   gravity or reactionary collision forces. This is the default body type
>   for physical objects in Box2D. Dynamic bodies can collide with all
>   body types.
>
> "static" — static bodies does not move under simulation and they
>   behave as if they have infinite mass. Static bodies can be moved
>   manually by the user, but they do not accept the application of
>   velocity. Static bodies collide only with dynamic bodies, not with
>   other static bodies or kinematic bodies.
>
> "kinematic" — kinematic bodies move under simulation only according to
>   their velocity. Kinematic bodies will not respond to forces like
>   gravity. They can be moved manually by the user, but normally they are
>   moved by setting their velocities. Kinematic bodies collide only with
>   dynamic bodies, not with other kinematic bodies or static bodies.